# Producing a specific ASCII character in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, special-characters

I'm used to holding the <kbd>left Alt</kbd> and entering the ASCII character whenever I'm using an unknown keyboard configuration and want to type a special character.

For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> makes a backslash (\).

That's on Windows. Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu?

Note: I also want to be able to use this in console mode. That means I don't want a solution involving software with a GUI.

Comment: There's a general question about whether it is even possible to do this the Windows way on AskUbuntu, at https://askubuntu.com/questions/588090/ .

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254477/ on Unix and Linux.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using Gnome (stock Ubuntu does) you can do that by holding down both the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys and typing `u` followed by the **hexadecimal** value of the character.

To produce the backslash `\`, you would hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>.

On Windows you type the decimal value while on Linux you type the hexadecimal value (which is usually shorter if you go in the higher numbers). The **u** stands for Unicode.

A pretty complete table of hexadecimal values can be found [here](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html). Warning, page can take a long time to load!

Comment: The "hexadecimal value" is in fact the Unicode codepoint, unlike "Alt codes" which are ASCII

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I needed ! Works everywhere like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Now I only need to learn all the codes in hexa.... :(

Comment: Does somebody know, how to get this work in Sublime Text?

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

Linux's console driver doesn't have a facility for entering characters this way... but it isn't really needed since shells can handle this themselves.

```
$ echo $'\x5c'
\
```

Comment: Thats a very nice method.... I can't even find it in the man pages of echo but it works! Is there a way to provide the decimal code instead of the hexidecimal one ? (I learned the decimal codes by heart)

Comment: Is there a way to use this when I'm in vi or nano ?

Comment: No, they can only be entered in hex (`\xNN`) or octal (`\NNN`). You can use `printf` if you want to see the hex code for a value. In vim you can type Ctrl-V U and then the 4-digit Unicode codepoint. Also, **QUOTING** section.

Comment: @Silence: (1) Because it's a feature of your shell (usually `bash`), not of `echo`.

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere In vi you can execute shell commands by prepending `:!` like `:!ls`. You can also insert the output into the current buffer using `:r !`. I often lack the tilde character so I use `:r !echo $'\x7e'`. A little more on that [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/180178/77503).

Answer (score 6):

Another option (but it does not insert a character by ASCII/Unicode code) is to activate the [ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) (like right <kbd>Alt</kbd> in my case), so that you can then type things like:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> → €
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> → é
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> → ê

etc.
In case you want to enter frequently used latin letters (as in Spanish, French, etc), this might be faster than having to learn the Unicode code points. It's all about having choice!

Comment: Don't you need an non-US keyboard layout for this?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: No, you need to enable a Compose key.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you're right. It seems that my XFCE 4.10 desktop environment didn't set the Compose key at all, but after setting it to the right Alt key, the answer worked (therefore +1 from me).

Answer (score 1):

From the [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#input) by Markus Kuhn:

> Extend your keyboard mapping using **xmodmap**. This is particularly convenient if your keyboard has an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, which is meant for exactly this purpose (some US keyboards have instead of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> just a right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, others lack that key entirely unfortunately, in which case some other key must be assigned the Mode_switch function). Write a file `~/.Xmodmap` with entries such as
>
> ```
> keycode 113 = Mode_switch Mode_switch
> keysym d = d NoSymbol degree        NoSymbol
> keysym m = m NoSymbol emdash        mu
> keysym n = n NoSymbol endash        NoSymbol
> keysym 2 = 2 quotedbl twosuperior   NoSymbol
> keysym 3 = 3 sterling threesuperior NoSymbol
> keysym 4 = 4 dollar   EuroSign      NoSymbol
> keysym space = space  NoSymbol      nobreakspace NoSymbol
> keysym minus = minus  underscore    U2212        NoSymbol
> keycode 34 = bracketleft  braceleft  leftsinglequotemark  leftdoublequotemark
> keycode 35 = bracketright braceright rightsinglequotemark rightdoublequotemark
> keysym KP_Subtract = KP_Subtract NoSymbol U2212    NoSymbol
> keysym KP_Multiply = KP_Multiply NoSymbol multiply NoSymbol
> keysym KP_Divide   = KP_Divide   NoSymbol division NoSymboll
> ```
>
> and load it with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from your X11 startup script into your X server. You will then find that you get with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> easily the following new characters out of your keyboard:
>
> - <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> → °
> - <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> → ‘

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what the OP is asking, but maybe it's enough for whoever is reading this.

Depending on your selected keyboard layout, you may already be able to type *some* unicode and ASCII characters; just like in macOS. Click on the language selector near the tray icon (if you have it), then `Show Keyboard Layout`, and have a look at the alternative characters of the individual keys.

For instance, you can type … (ellipsis) with <kbd>right ALT + .</kbd>, and ÷ (division) with <kbd>right ALT + SHIFT + .</kbd>.

Moreover, these keystrokes even work in Sublime, which proved to be more stubborn towards <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + U</kbd>.